# Power BI date relationship not working on calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following calculated date column in the model:

```
ForecastDate = [SowingDate] + [EstimatedDays]
```

The `SowingDate` is a date column and `EstimatedDays` is a decimal column, but containing whole numbers. `ForecastDate` has an inactive relationship to the calendar table. I have calculated a forecast amount measure using this relationship, and it is working fine.

The problem is, that if `EstimatedDays` is null, I want to use the value 40 as a default. However, when I change the measure to any of the following, the forecast measure displays nothing, although the dates appear in the column `ForecastDate` without errors.

```
ForecastDate = [SowingDate] + IF([EstimatedDays] = 0, 40, [EstimatedDays])
ForecastDate = [SowingDate] + MAX([EstimatedDays], 40)
ForecastDate = [SowingDate] + [EstimatedDays] + if([EstimatedDays] = 0, 40,0)
ForecastDate = [SowingDate] + [EstimatedDays] + 5
```

Why is the relationship getting broken by the latter calculations but not with the first? And how could I use a default value in case of null?

EDIT: Now I'm really stunned. I replaced null values and zeros in the query editor with 40, and used the first measure, and even this breaks the forecast amount measure.

Comment: What's your forecast measure?

Comment: `GrowthForecast = CALCULATE([Quantity], FILTER(FormData, [EventTypeId] = 1),USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date], FormData[ForecastDate]))`

Comment: Nesting two calculate functions did the trick: `GrowthForecast = CALCULATE(CALCULATE([Quantity], FILTER(FormData, [EventTypeId] = 1)), USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date], FormData[ForecastDate]))`. I'd still like to undestand why, though.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, thanks for looking into it. At least I got it working. Actually I think I've had problems before with measures using some other criteria with USERELATIONSHIP, but can't be sure.